# Azure blob's block list is empty, but blob is not empty! How can this be?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

**This issue in a nutshell:**

A block blob can be created with a single PUT request. This will create a blob with committed content but the blob **will not have any committed blocks**!

This means that you cannot assume that the concatenation of committed blocks is the same as the committed content.

When working with block blobs you'll have to pay extra attention to blobs with empty block lists, because such blobs *may or may not* be empty!

---

*The original question:*

One of our storage blobs in an Azure account has an empty block list, although it is non-empty.

I'm retrieving the block list like this (C#):

```cs
foreach (var block in _cloudBlob.DownloadBlockList(
    BlockListingFilter.Committed, 
    AccessCondition.GenerateLeaseCondition(_leaseId)))
{
    // ...
}
```

The code in the `foreach` block is NOT executed. The returned list is empty.

However, the blob reports that it has a non-zero length when I check: `_cloudBlob.Properties.Length`

I can also download the blob and see that it is not empty.

Am I missing something? How can the block list be empty when the blob is not?!

It does not matter whether I use `BlockListingFilter.Committed`, `BlockListingFilter.Uncommitted` or `BlockListingFilter.All`; the list is still empty!

**UPDATE**

I have copied this blob to a public container so that this issue can be reproduced by anyone.

Here's how to reproduce what I'm unable to understand:

First get blob properties from Azure using the REST API:

```
HEAD http://dfdev.blob.core.windows.net/pub/test HTTP/1.1
Host: dfdev.blob.core.windows.net
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 66
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Last-Modified: Sat, 02 Feb 2013 09:37:19 GMT
ETag: 0x8CFCF40075A5F31
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 4b149a7e-2fcd-4ab4-8d53-12ef047cbfa1
x-ms-version: 2009-09-19
x-ms-lease-status: unlocked
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob
Date: Sat, 02 Feb 2013 09:40:54 GMT
```

The response headers tell us that this is a block blob and that it has a length of 66 bytes.

Now retrieve the block list from:

http://dfdev.blob.core.windows.net/pub/test?comp=blocklist

Response body:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><BlockList><CommittedBlocks /></BlockList>
```

So, the blob does not have any committed blocks, still it has a length of 66 bytes!

Is this a bug or have I misunderstood something?

Please help me out!

**UPDATE 2**

I've found that if I upload the blob like this:

```cs
container.GetBlockBlobReference("put-only")
    .UploadFromStream(File.OpenRead("test-blob"));
```

...then a single PUT request is sent to Azure and the blob gets an empty block list (just like above).

However, if I upload the blob like this:

```cs
var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("put-block");
string blockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Guid.NewGuid().ToByteArray());
blob.PutBlock(blockId, File.OpenRead("test-blob"), null);
blob.PutBlockList(new string[] { blockId });
```

...then two requests are sent to Azure (one for putting the block and another for putting the block list).

The second blob gets a non-empty block list.

Why won't a single PUT yield a block list?

Can't we rely on that the concatenation of a blob's committed blocks are equal to the blob's actual content?!

If not, how shall we determine when the block list is OK and when it's not??

**UPDATE 3**

I've implemented a workaround for this that I think suffice in the case where we encountered this problem. In case we discover an empty block list AND a blob length that is greater than zero, then we'll assume that everything is OK (although it really isn't) and go ahead and rewrite that data using Put Block and Put Block List at the next opportunity.

However, although this will do the trick in our case, it is still very confusing that a non-empty block blob can have an empty list of committed blocks!!

Is this by-design in Azure? Can anyone explain what's going on?

**UPDATE 4**

Microsoft [confirmed this issue on the MSDN forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredata/thread/c2092669-426c-4a4d-bf89-a028f01fa54f) too. Quote from Allen Chen:

> I've confirmed with the product team. This is a normal behavior. The x-ms-blob-content-length header is the size of the committed blob. In your case you use Put Blob API so all content is uploaded in a single API and is committed in the same request. As a result in the Get Block List API's response you see the x-ms-blob-content-length header has value of 66 which means the committed blob size.
>
> We have been aware of the issue that the MSDN document of the Get Block List API is not quite clear on this and will work on it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you also identified with your tests, querying the list of blocks of a block blob uploaded using [Put Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179451.aspx) will return an empty list. This is by design.

UploadFromStream API in the Storage Client Library makes a couple of checks before deciding whether to upload a blob using a single Put Blob operation or a sequence of Put Block operations followed by a Put Block List. One property that changes this behavior is [SingleBlobUploadThresholdInBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobclient.singleblobuploadthresholdinbytes.aspx).

Comment: So this means that we cannot trust that the concatenation of committed blocks are equal to the blob's actual content. We must therefore have special handling for all block blobs that have an empty block list, right? Are there any other special cases when the concatenation of committed blocks are not equal to the actual content?

Comment: If the blob was committed using a block list (Put Block List), you can always query the same list back. If a block list was not committed (meaning that Put Blob was used), the block list is going to be empty.

Comment: Ok. Well that's clear. However, doesn't that mean that we actually have three kinds of blobs; Page blobs; Block blobs WITH blocks; and Block blobs WITHOUT blocks!? If we for example want to append data to a block blob then we'll need to handle the two "kinds" of block blobs completely different. This sure feels like a bad design to me, but maybe I'm missing something? Anyway, you've answered my question - this IS by design. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you are in control of you Architecture and you surely need to append content to the end of blob (always, or occasionally) I suggest that you always upload your blobs with blocks. Doing so, you will always have blocks. However I would challenge you to think a bit about the [Blob Snapshots](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh488361.aspx). Instead of appending to end, create a snapshot, and do entire upload of new content (if scenario allows this behavior).

Comment: Appending data by uploading the entire new blob is not a good solution. Consider the case when we only want to append a few hundred bytes to a large existing blob. Having to upload everything for this change would be bad design. When blobs are created by appending only, then there is no problem. However, we need to support cases when blobs have been created by a separate tool. Those tools may very well upload the blob using a single PUT operation and thereby create a block blob **without** blocks.

Comment: On the other hand. Uploading the whole content would be needed only for cases with blobs without blocks. Such a blobs are small. There is a limit (4MB) up-to the blocks are not created.